# cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-3.5, opencv3.1

This is my first attempt to detect faces and eyes in OpenCV 3.1. Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cam = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    tf, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        img = cv.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScalenter code heree(roi_gray)

        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            cv.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        print(tf)
        cv.imshow('my cam', img)
        key = cv.waitKey(1)
        if key  == 27:
            break
cam.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I got this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp, line 1639
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hedon/PycharmProjects/deneme_1.1/ilk.py", line 13, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1639: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale
```

Can anybody told where is my mistake? I've also tried:

`gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BAYER_GR2GRAY)` as PyCharm suggested. Same error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 1 && dcn == 1) in cv::demosaicing, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\imgproc\src\demosaicing.cpp, line 1630
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hedon/PycharmProjects/deneme_1.1/ilk.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BAYER_BG2GRAY)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\imgproc\src\demosaicing.cpp:1630: error: (-215) scn == 1 && dcn == 1 in function cv::demosaicing
```

Comment: Please edit your title. Titles that read like: "so and so doesn't work", are inappropriate titles. They are ambiguous and give no insight into what your problem is. Always try to ask yourself before creating your title: **"does this summarize my problem in a clear and concise way?"**

Comment: The first error is because you didn't load correctly the classifier. Check the path to the xml files. The second error is due to the _non-sense_ conversion you're trying to do. And they are two really different errors, and **not** the "same error"!

Comment: @Miki Ooops, I just confused. They're completely different errors. Thanks. I copied xml files to the same folder with .py file. Isn't it OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

is telling you that the classifier is *empty*, because you didn't load the xml files correctly.

Use the full path to the xml files to be sure to load them properly.

Answer (score 0):

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 1 && dcn == 1) in cv::demosaicing, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\imgproc\src\demosaicing.cpp, line 1630
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/hedon/PycharmProjects/deneme_1.1/ilk.py", line 11, in 
>       gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BAYER_BG2GRAY)
>   cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\imgproc\src\demosaicing.cpp:1630: error: (-215) scn == 1 && dcn == 1 in function cv::demosaicing

this problem from :

```
cv2.imread
```

you should check if the images exist in the path you give ,
then check the count variable if it have valid number.